# Android: How to make an apk configurable?

Tags: android

Within my android app, I have several configurable settings (like user/pw, etc).
By request of my users, I need to make these settings configurable from outside.
Therefore, in my app, I’ve created a properties file (in the assets folder) and I’m reading the settings from there.

```
    AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
    InputStream inputStream = assetManager.open("myapp.properties");
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.load(inputStream);
```

But this doesn’t solve my problem:

I export the signed apk  .
Install it -> fine.
Open the apk, change the properties, save, close the apk.
Install it -> failure

Solution is to sign the apk again.
But I cannot expect this from my users.
So my question is: how can I modify the content of an apk without re-signing it?
Or is there any other proposal?
(I cannot use any UI in my app for this purpose)
Or is there a very easy tool for generating key+sign (I've used cmd-line)
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can't you just save those properties in SharedPreferences, for example? 
See: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Comment: I don't understand the question. You want to save user preferences? You don't have to modify the apk for that. That is in fact impossible. You can't change anything that is compiled into your apk. You can use `SharedPreferences` to for easy key/value storing of data, or if you have more complex data you use a database. There are multiple native persistence mechanisms in Android.

Comment: You could experiment with expansion files http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html, they are meant for something else but it may work if you deactivate the length check.

Comment: Your implementation of "saving outside" is wrong. Make a settings activity and save prefs to SharedPreferences.

Comment: IMHO Shared preferences is not a help, because the customer wants to configure the app before it is delivered to the store or the enduser. You could make a WebAPI which serves the configuration as json, or try it with a expasion file, or could write a bash script to resign the apk which hast to be run before upload

Comment: @A.S. I thought about the WebAPI as well, but the App would always fetch the same resource as this is hardcoded in the APK. How to differentiate in this case?

Comment: sorry do not understand? you mean it will always fetch it on every startup? No just load it at first start and then save it to sharedpreferences, and only load when there are no entries in the sharedprefs... It is like those nasty first loading screens many games do have. They also load some data like (startmoney, money for some items, special features etc pp)

Comment: @A.S. All the variants will use the same APK file, so they will fetch the same resource even when they do it just once.

Comment: aaaaaaaah i see, are they all provided via gplay?

Comment: Thanks, dear friends! Yes, A.S. is right, SharedPreferences wouldn't help. So I'll have to go for one of the proposals. Thanks very much for the responses!

Comment: this will be some dirty hack. What is the scenario overall? They don't want you to have some sensitive information (passwords or something..) or they just want to can change the properties and reupload the apk without the need to call (and pay) you?

Comment: the second assumption is correct. It is about some customizing that shouldn't be in the UI of the app.

Comment: the only way seems to be a web service configuration.